# react-flow-renderer export as image

Tags: reactjs, canvas

I am using "react-flow-renderer" library to draw a diagram in my react project. I have to implement "export as image" functionality so that i can export the generated diagram as a png/jpeg. Library doesn't implement this functionality and i am not able to make it work by drawing on canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using something like use-react-screenshot, a third party library to save your flow chart in jpg/png format.

https://codesandbox.io/s/rf55oe?file=/src/App.js

Comment: we cant download the full screenshot with this.